# copy and replace to folders to another fastest way - linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, cp

I have a three folders: **core**, **project** and **merge** with many files inside.
I want to delete all files and folders (including dot files) inside the **merge** folder, and then copy all files (including dot files) from the **core** folder to the **merge** folder, as well as merge all files in the **project** folder into the **merge** files.

**Situations**

1. How can i remove all files and folders (including dot files) from special folders, without removing them? (`rm -rf /path/to/folder/*` did not delete files and folders.)
2. What is fastest way to copy (with and without merge and replace) all files recursively from special folder to another one (including dot files)? (`tar -cf my.tar path/; tar -xf my.tar`)

I'm using tar but there are too many files and I need a faster way.

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing, can you provide some example filenames and what you want the end result to be?

Comment: @mgorven situation 1: `rm -rf /path/to/folder/*` did not remove dot files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Deletion

```
rm -r merge/* merge/.*
rm: "." and ".." may not be removed
```

You can safely ignore that warning. Personally, I'd probably just `rm -r merge` and nuke the directory itself.

### Copying

```
cp -r core/ merge/
```

... but that will overwrite the merge directory.

```
cd core && find . -exec cp "{}" "../merge/{}" \;
```

A bit slower and harder to write, but functional and doesn't clobber the parent directory.

### All at once

```
rsync -av --delete core/ merge/
```